# hasOneThrough relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

A contract has a representative (which is a user).

[image]

Currently I get this relationship with an belongsTo directly like this in my Contract model:

```php
class Contract extends Model
{
    public function representative()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

I would like to be able to retrieve this relationship through the organization_user table and retrieve the "position" attribute.
I think I should use the hasOneThrough relationship but I can't get what I'm looking for.

```php
class Contract extends Model
{
    public function representative()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, OrganizationUser::class);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you're in a position to change your DB structure, but it seems to me that your table contracts and organization_user are duplicating each other, storing the same data.

Would it make sense to leave only one table organization_user as a pivot table with the position?

Then you wouldn't need to make the big loop over few relationship to get the needed data.